# Class must either be declared abstract or implement member

Tags: scala, constructor, dao

For reading DB values (mySQL), I am planning to implement a DAO in scala. I was checking this code (in java) for reference -- 
https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc

I am new to DAO and scala, and I am facing a probably simple issue in the constructor, but unable to fix it

Here is the constructor I created for the purpose:

```
class Pet ()
{
  var name: String
  var owner: String
  var species: String
  var sex: String
  var birth: String
  //var death: String

  def getname()=name
  def setname(name:String): Unit ={
    this.name=name
  }

  def getowner()=owner
  def setowner(owner: String)={
    this.owner=owner
  }

  def getspecies()=species
  def setspecies(species:String)={
    this.species=species
  }

  def getsex()=sex
  def setsex(sex:String)={
    this.sex=sex
  }

  def getbirth()=birth
  def setbirth(birth:String)={
    this.birth=birth
  }

  /*
  def getdeath()=birth
  def setdeath()={
    this.death=death
  }
  */



}
```

Here is how I want to add member variables to the Pet object

```
      val petObj = new Pet()

      petObj.setname(rs.getString("name"))
      petObj.setowner(rs.getString("owner"))
      petObj.setspecies(rs.getString("species"))
      petObj.setsex(rs.getString("sex"))
      petObj.setbirth(rs.getString("birth"))
```

In the above constructor, I am getting a compile time error

> > Class Pet must either be declared abstract or implement member 'owner'

Comment: All the `var` variables need an initial, default, value. Something like `name: String = _` or maybe `owner: String = ""`.

Comment: Please do not write **Java** in **Scala**. You may try to use an immutable case class instead, an relay on `copy` to modify it. BTW, you do not need the setters and getters, given your variables are public, they expose both already.

Comment: Thanks. Initializing a default value solved the issue